# Struggling to unset an environment variable in bash

Tags: environment-variables, unset, bash

I have previously set an environment variable using:

```
echo export "AVARIABLE=example" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

but now after using:

```
unset AVARIABLE
```

the env var remains when I open a new shell? What am I doing wrong here? Even running:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

does not work?

Comment: You're only unsetting in your current shell, not across shell sessions.

Comment: @Madbreaks apologies i should have been clearer: even in my current shell when i use echo command it still runs. i can't unset it even in my current shell.

Answer (score 4):

If you are opening a new shell, about the first thing it does is to source `~/.bash_profile`.  And there, the variable is set again.

If you want to get rid of it permanently, edit your `~/.bash_profile` to remove the line in question again.  (This will only take effect for new sessions.)

If you only want to unset it in your current shell, then `unset` is fine but as you've seen, it won't affect new invocations of the shell.